# How to change dropdown combobox value using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I know this may be kind of a simple question, but cant seem to find an answer anywhere, I have a form in my site, with multiple form elements like combobox, text, radio buttons, checks etc, My requirement is to change the values of those form elements when a user from dropdown combobox is selected, I have successfully implemented that functionality with all the form elements except for the comboboxes, I cant seem to find any way to change the options of the combobox...

Comment: Google about `html select selectedIndex`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you included the jQuery tag,

```
select.val(value);
```

where `select` is the jQuery select element and `value` is the value.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9rLtT/)

```
<select>
    <option value="1">First option</option>
    <option value="2">Second option</option>
    <option value="3">Third option</option>
</select>

<script>
    $('select').val('2');
</script>
```

Comment: i have successfully done the input elements, it the combobox i have trouble with

Comment: By `input`, I meant `select` :P Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

New option can be added to the combobox as below

$('< option value=’Value’ > Sample Value < /option >').appendTo('#ComboId');

a dropdown value can be selected by

$('#ComboId').val('Value');